# MoPub Full SDK 2.3.0 Improper IDFA usage

Tags: ios, mopub

During my IOS app validation, warning shows "Improper Advertising Identifier [IDFA] Usage. Your app contains the IDFA API but you have not indicated its usage on the Prepare for Upload". I have updated the admob SDK inside with the latest. Do I have to tick using IDFA during the preparation for upload?

Regards
Hammer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you are using the Ad Identifier in your own code or in third party libraries such as mopub, then Apple requires you to fill in and check the appropriate forms on the IDFA questionnaire prior to upload.

> Specifically, the section advises app developers that the IDFA is “the only way to offer targeted ads” and offers three use cases which they must also check, if in place:
>
> > Serve advertisements within the app
> >
> > Attribute this app installation to a previously served advertisement
> >
> > Attribute an action taken within this app to a previously served advertisement

[Source](http://techcrunch.com/2014/04/11/apple-developers-must-now-agree-to-ad-identifier-rules-or-risk-app-store-rejection/)